# why am i getting this error in python if statement?

Tags: python, python-requests, coding-style

please help me with this error!!

#Program by Gerontius Leo

```
hours=int(input("Enter the number of hours spend on Surfing :")

if (hours >= 5):
    print("The cost of Surfing is Rs"+str(eval(hours*20)))
    else:
        print("The cost of surfing is Rs 101")
```

error:
File "/home/main.py", line 5
if (hours >= 5):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: As with so many intro syntax errors, this is due to parenthesis imbalance.

Comment: Two things:
In your first line you are missing a closing bracket.
Second, the else must be on the same level (so one less indent) as the if.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a parenthesis in the first line and the indentation of the if/else statement.
I recommend you to read about "Python indentation" in geeksforgeeks for example.

```
hours=int(input("Enter the number of hours spend on Surfing :"))

if (hours >= 5):
    print("The cost of Surfing is Rs"+str(eval(hours*20)))
else:
    print("The cost of surfing is Rs 101")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two problems with your code

1. The first problem is with the brackets in the first line, you did not close it, hence the error.
2. The second problem is with the indentation of the else statement, It does not have the same number of indents as the if statement it trails, in simple words the `else` statement you are trying to add is registered as a `else` statement that trails another `if` statement inside the first `if` block, which does not exist.

here is how the code should have been

```py
hours=int(input("Enter the number of hours spend on Surfing :")) # fix 1 : added an ending bracket

if (hours >= 5):
    print("The cost of Surfing is Rs"+str(eval(hours*20)))
else: # fix 2 : indented the else block the complement the intended if block
    print("The cost of surfing is Rs 101")
```